# Can I use something like Mac 'alias' inside Dropbox, so that I only need one copy of each file?

Tags: filesystems, dropbox

I have a large image collection, and sometimes an image fits into multiple categories: location, picture of my sister, etc. So, I have the SAME image in multiple folders based on these categories. However, I'm running out of space on Dropbox (which I need because I work in different locations), and am trying to find a way to use some kind of link to reference the duplicate files. I don't know if it's possible to use something like a Mac 'alias'.

-Clayton

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear to be supported.  See http://www.paulingraham.com/dropbox-and-symlinks.html